# Distribution of an iOS app outside Appstore but to public users

Tags: ios, app-store

We have built an iOS app for another company as a partnership. The tricky part comes now.

The end users are unknown to us from a device perspective but we have knowledge about their ssn for example. This is due to the fact that only registered users are allowed to log in.

This complicates things for us when we soon need to have these apps deployed. Since we cant now for sure when new users will be added to our DB we need to be able to distribute this publicly...

But apple see this as a B2B and has therefore declined us access to appstore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what the problem would be, [Apple offers a B2B program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) for apps that need to be distributed privately.

Comment: Is the app for employees of the other company or customers of the other company?

Comment: It is for eployees of several other companies. However we will never now exactly who the people are.. (this is so hard to explain for someone outside our project :) )

Comment: It sounds like you may need to submit an appeal. You can have apps on the App Store that require a login (e.g. the SalesForce app), so it may be possible to distribute via the App Store.  But if the several other companies are your clients then you may need to provide your app to those companies via B2B and then they distribute the app to their employees.